Apc Customize UI++ activityBarTop vscode set item background
I want to give each item a background and space and center them but my code is not working please help me
enter image description here
I tried to solve this problem with the following code, but it didn't work
"apc.stylesheet": {
    ".tabs-container .tab.active": {
        "background": "#3b3c45 !important"
    },
    ".scrollbar": {
        "background": "#21222f !important"
    },
    ".activityBarTop": {
      "text-align":"center"
  }
}


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
